# Padding a hexadecimal string with zeros

Tags: python, python-2.x, formatting

I'm given a hexadecimal number in string form with a leading `"0x"` that may contain 1-8 digits, but I need to pad the number with zeros so that it always has 8 digits (10 characters including the `"0x"`).

For example:

- `"0x123"` should become `"0x00000123"`.
- `"0xABCD12"` should become `"0x00ABCD12"`.
- `"0x12345678"` should be unchanged.

I am guaranteed to never see more than 8 digits, so this case does not need to be handled.

Right now, I have this coded as:

```
padded = '0x' + '0' * (10 - len(mystring)) + mystring[2:]
```

It works, but feels ugly and unpythonic.  Any suggestions for a cleaner method?

Comment: e.g. `"0x" + ("0"*8 + s[2:])[-8:]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for the `.zfill` method on strings. From the docs:

> ```
> Help on built-in function zfill:
>
> zfill(...)
>     S.zfill(width) -> string
>
>     Pad a numeric string S with zeros on the left, to fill a field
>     of the specified width.  The string S is never truncated.
> ```

Your code can be written as:

```
def padhexa(s):
    return '0x' + s[2:].zfill(8)

assert '0x00000123' == padhexa('0x123')
assert '0x00ABCD12' == padhexa('0xABCD12')
assert '0x12345678' == padhexa('0x12345678')
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest interpreting the input as a number, then using standard number-formatting routines.

```
padded = str.format('0x{:08X}', int(mystring, 16))
```

The string → int → string round trip may seem silly, but it is also beneficial in that it provides validation of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this:

```
def format_word(word, prefix=None, size=None):
    if prefix is None:
        prefix = '0x'
    if size is None:
        size = 2
    if not isinstance(word, int):
        word = int(word, 16)
    if word > 2**(8 * size) - 1:
        raise ValueError('word too great')
    return '{prefix}{word:0{padding}X}'.format(
            prefix=prefix,
            word=word,
            padding=2 * size)
```

Using `None` as defaults and assigning true defaults later makes it easier to wrap the function.

```
def format_word(word, prefix=None, size=None):
    if prefix is None:
        prefix = '0x'
    if size is None:
        size = 2
```

If `word` isn't already a `int` try to convert it. It'll choke if it's not a `str`, `bytes`, or `bytearray`. We need the type check because `int(word, 16)` would choke if `word` was already an `int.

```
if not isinstance(word, int):
    word = int(word, 16)
```

Check that the `word` isn't going break the formatting.

```
if word > 2**(8 * size) - 1:
    raise ValueError('word too great')
```

Finally, format the word, using keywords to decouple the string to the argument order.

```
return '{prefix}{word:0{padding}X}'.format(
        prefix=prefix,
        word=word,
        padding=2 * size)
```